# How to get only two fields from the table by linq query?

Tags: sql-server, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a **.net core(v 3.1)** in which i have installed **Microsoft SQL Server** database provider nuget package for **Entity Framework Core**.

I want to get only two feilds from the database?

> Error : Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string Name, string Number>>'
> to 'ExampleAuth.Model.Employee'. An explicit conversion exists (are
> you missing a cast?)

```
public Employee GetById(int id)
    {
        var response = db.Employee.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => new{x.Name,x.Number});
        return response;
    }
```

API Is...

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetById/{id}")]
    public Employee GetById(int id)
    {
        if (id != 0)
        {
            return bl.GetById(id);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("! No Data Found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: <sql> is a language - supported by many products. Which one are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server database provider for Entity Framework Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution...
it is look like..

```
public Employee GetById(int id)
    {
        var response = db.Employee
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Select(x => new Employee{Name = x.Name,Number = x.Number}).FirstOrDefault();
        return response;
    }
```

Thanks to all...

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things. Firstly, you are trying to return the entire query rather than a single employee. Secondly, you are creating an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) rather than an instance of the `Employee` class. Your code should look something like this:

```
var response = db.Employee
    .Single(x => x.Id == id) // Use single to get an individual item
    .Select(x => new Employee // Make a new Employee object
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Number = x.Number
    });
```

Now `response` contains a single `Employee` object. Note this will throw an exception if there is no matching employee with that ID, but that is likely a good idea. You could handle that by replacing `Single` with `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: Thank you sir, I got a solution from your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this below query

```
var response = (from objEmp in db.Employee where objEmp.Id == id select new
    {
        Name = objEmp.Name,
        Number = objEmp.Number
    }).FirstOrDefault();

if(response  != null)
{
response.Name // For access name
response.Number // For access number
}
```